# How to trigger pop-up in app via notification click even when app is not running

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to implement a timer in my app. The timer runs in a foreground service, and it works as intended.

Upon clicking the the notification, it should a) open the Timer activity (which is the Main activity) and b) open a one-time pop up asking if you want to stop it. (not the full extent of the pop up, but I've simplified it for this example).

I am having difficulty with this functionality because of a few challenges/limitations. My two main methods is using RxJava and broadcast receivers via Pending intents.

If the app is open and in the foreground, I can use an observable via a broadcast intent and listen to it the Timer activity. when it receives a value, it shows the pop up. Simple.

If the app is closed or in the background, I've tried using a pending intent with a key-value extra such as ("should-show-pop-up",true). I then check in the onStart method if this extra exists and if true, show the pop up. However, now it shows the pop up every time I open the app. If the app goes in the background and then back to the foreground, the activity still holds that extra and it triggers the pop up.

So bottom line: how do I open my app and show a pop up if a user presses a notification? Even if the app is closed or in background

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to use a separate `Activity` for this not your main `Activity`. When you create the `Intent` to put into the `Notification`, add the following flags:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
```

This will ensure that the `Intent` with the "extras" does not become the "default `Intent` to use when your app is launched from the HOME screen"